# PyAutoGUI click() function will not register in certain applications

Tags: python, user-interface, automation

I am currently trying to write a script to automate the ATTO disk benchmark GUI.  I can use the script to successfully locate images in the GUI, but I can not get any clicks generated by the script to register in the application.  I have modified the script to test if I could use the PyAutoGUI package to click things in other applications, and have been able to successfully click things in other applications.  Has anyone else had this issue with other applications using the PyAutoGUI package, and if so did you ever find any solution to the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to run your script with administrative privileges. If you are  using Powershell then run powershell as administrator